# How to interpret nested GLMM results

Tags: r, glmm, nested-models

I have a dataset like the following:

```
ID outc Month var1 Category1 Category2 Category3
1  0    1     .05  1         0         0
1  0    1     .05  0         1         0
1  1    1     .05  0         0         1
...
```

Where `outc` equates to a percentage of a total (dichotomized into above or below 50%), `ID` equates to a location ID #, `Month` is the month of observation, `var1` is a continuous variable, and each respective `Category_n` are the specific category that equates to the `outc` during that month for that location. Notably, for all unique `ID` and `Month` variables, there can only be one `outc` equaling one.

I am looking to analyze how `var1` relates to the binary `outc` owned by each Category over time.

Do do this, I fit a GLMM model in R like so:

```
library(lme4)
mod <- glmer(formula=df$outc ~ df$var1 + df$Category1 +
df$Category2 + 
df$var1*df$Category1 + 
df$var1*df$Category2 + 
(1 | df$ID),
data = df,
family=binomial(link=logit))
```

My model properly converges, and I am left with an output table similar to the following:

```
Fixed effects:
                                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                        -0.60773    0.03380 -17.982  < 2e-16 ***
test6$var1                         -9.49762    3.94902  -2.405  0.01617 *  
test6$Category1                    -0.83719    0.06794 -12.322  < 2e-16 ***
test6$Category2                    -1.70239    0.08788 -19.372  < 2e-16 ***
test6$var1:test6$Category1         -18.38166    9.37067  -1.962  0.04981 *  
test6$var1:test6$Category2          25.13745    9.18822   2.736  0.00622 **
```

I am having difficulty interpreting my results. To me, it seems that the resulting model is essentially a nested model, saying: "In areas where category 1 is found, a decrease in variable 1 increases the odds of being in the high percent category, and in areas where category 2 is found, variable 1 increases the odds of being in the high percent category".

Additionally, when I run the model only looking at one specific category like so:

```
mod <- glmer(formula=df$outc ~ df$var1 + 
df$Category1 +
df$var1*df$Category1 + 
(1 | df$ID),
data = df,
family=binomial(link=logit))
```

My fixed effects coefficients are different. My intuition tells me that my data are either set up improperly, or I am asking the wrong question of my data. How do I interpret the mixed effects model with interaction, given what I have presented here?

Comment: Are the categories 1,2,3 just levels of an overall variable, Category? If so, make a new factor with three levels and use that for your model.

Comment: “Notably, for all unique ID and Month variables, there can only be one outc equaling one.“ then the data are not stochastic, so hard to justify a model.

Comment: @JTH Essentially, the categories are related types of diseases from surveillance data. A case of surveillance data can only be one of the three Categories. The outc variable (prior to being dichotomized) is the percentage of total surveillance cases that are that specific category. I am interested if var1 is related to the percent share of surveillance data that a Category can have. I.e, does the value of var1 influence the odds of percentage of surveillance cases for each Category being greater than 50% or less than 50%.

Comment: @JTH Perhaps I should be doing a multinomial logistic regression?

Comment: It would be best to not dichotomize outc, because binning a variable is loss of information. I propose you start with `fit <- lmer(outc ~ vars1 * category + (1|ID), data) where outc is not dichotomized, and the categories are rolled into one factor.

Comment: @JTH I did try that, I wanted to avoid log transforming my dependent variable. The dependent variable was distributed with two bimodal peaks near 0 and 100